# Solve linear algebra expression $- \nabla . G$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Let's consider the vector $G$

\begin{equation}
G = \begin{pmatrix}
-x(\alpha + \beta) + y \beta \\
x \beta - y (\alpha + \beta)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

with constants $\alpha$ and  $\beta$. I would like to solve $$- \nabla . G$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector function $G=(G_1,G_2)$ (*not* a matrix) has derivatives $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha-\beta\\\beta\end{pmatrix},\qquad\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=\begin{pmatrix}\beta\\-\alpha-\beta\end{pmatrix}$$ Hence $$\nabla\cdot G=\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial y}=-2(\alpha+\beta)$$